# DotNetOpenAuth.Oauth2.IAuthorizationState duplicate definition

Tags: c#, nuget, dotnetopenauth, visual-studio-express, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to compile a sample to connect to Google Calendar.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012

I have downloaded the required libraries with NuGet

I get this error when I try to build the solution:

> Error 1   The type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState' exists in
>   both 'C:\Users\Cesc\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Prova1\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.5.0.0-alpha1\lib\net45-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.dll' and 'C:\Users\Cesc\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Prova1\packages\Google.Apis.Authentication.1.5.0-beta\lib\net40\DotNetOpenAuth.dll' C:\Users\Cesc\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Prova1\Prova1\Program.cs 120 20  Prova1

I've tried to remove some of the libraries but then I get missing references.

I've googled about it but I've not been able to find any solution

Thanks for your help

Cesc

Comment: Which library are you referencing in the code? try using uninstall-package command to remove both the package completely, and then again try installing only one package.

Comment: I list the references:
`DotNetOpenAuth
DotNetOpenAuth.Core
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Common
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientAuthorization
Google.Apis
Google.Apis.Authentication.Oauth2
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Google.Apis.PlatformServices
log4net
Microsoft.CSharp
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
Newtonsoft.Json
System
System.Configuration
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Net
System.Net.Http
System.Net.Http.Extensions
System.Net.Http.Formatting
System.Net.Http.Primitives`

Comment: ... `System.Net.Http.WebRequest, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq, Validation and Zlib.Portable`
In the code the references are: `System;
System.Collections.Generic;
System.Configuration;
System.Data;
System.Data.OleDb;
System.Diagnostics;
System.Linq;
System.Text;
System.Threading.Tasks;
System.Xml.Serialization;
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

Google.Apis.Authentication;
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
Google.Apis.Util;`

Comment: Can you remove the DotNetOpenAuth packages, by uninstall-package? Currently we use the DotNetOpenAuth.dll in our Google.Apis library, but hopefully from our next version we will be able to avoid that with our own implementation of OAuth2.

Comment: Hi, it resolves the problem, but then I get some new problems...

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it got built, but when I ran the sample it didn't work, as it was looking for missing assemblies...
I've been looking for different libraries from Nuget, but now all is falling like a card's castle...
I'll try to remove all nuget packages and to get them again....

Comment: Now I'm in the point that builds again but when I run it, asking for NativeApplicationClient.cs ... I don't know what library am I missing...

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any solution yet?